# Powershell command to upload CSV to QuestDB

Tags: powershell, questdb

I can upload csv file to QuestDB on Linux using

```bash
curl -F data=@AllTrades.csv http://localhost:9000/imp?name=AllTrade
```

and it works correctly. How can I upload on Windows using Powershell? I tried

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://localhost:9000/imp?name=AllTrade" -Method Post -InFile "C:\path\to\AllTrades.csv"
```

but this got rejected. What would be the identical equivalent of the above `curl` command in `Powershell`?

Comment: "but this got rejected." - what kind of response did you get, any error messages you can share?

Comment: Please https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78074973/edit the question. Copy and paste, as text, any error messages into the question.

Comment: QuestDB disconnects, no error as such. It expects multipart form upload this is probably the difference between the commands